# pdbedit failed during openldap user creation with samba support

Tags: samba, openldap

I am running Lucid. I have setup openldap and samba a while ago, this problem existed since then and I still don't know how to fix it. I use webmin's LDAP client to create a "testuser" account, and get following error:

```
failed to save user : /usr/bin/pdbedit failed :
pdb_set_user_sid_from_string: -21020 isn't a valid SID!
init_sam_from_ldap: no sambaSID or sambaSID attribute found for this user atest
ldapsam_getsampwnam: init_sam_from_ldap failed for user 'testuser'!
ldapsam_add_sam_account: User 'testuser' already in the base, with samba attributes
```

I think SAMBA and OpenLDAP integration is not working corectly. Even with above error, "testuser" account is created. I can login with this account via SSH, but I can't login to Samba server on the same server. The last line of the error indicates some configuration is overlapped, but I don't know where and how to fix it.

**Update:**

Here is SAMBA setting section in LDAP users and groups configuration page of Webmin:

[image: Samba setting]

And

Samba version 3.4.7
LDAP protocol version 3

**Update 2:**

The error disappeared after I copied and pasted the sambaID for the samba server from "LDAP client -> LDAP Browser". So the input for "Domain SID for Samba3" looks something like:

S-1-5-22-3845707085-2256048510-3517135715.

Now samba user is created, but I still can't login to the samba server. The problem now is with password sync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried following command to add a testuser account with group ID of 10000:

```
sudo smbldap-useradd -a -P testuser
```

got error:

```
Can't call method "get_value" on an undefined value at /usr/sbin/smbldap-useradd line 231, <DATA> line 466.
```

Looking at the script /usr/sbin/smbldap-useradd I found that I have to specify a group ID for this new user. So next command:

```
sudo smbldap-useradd -a -P -g 10000 testuser
```

Where 10000 is the group id of intended LDAP group. I got this error:

```
Error: SID not set for unix group 10000
check if your unix group is mapped to an NT group
```

I went a head and sync the usergroup by going to "Samba Windows File Sharing" module of webmin, and added a samba group which also connected to the Unix/LDAP group that has id of 10000. A screenshot in case someone is still confused:
[image: Setting for Samba group]

And the problem solved :-)

I also went ahead and setup users and group sync in "Samba Windows File Sharing" to prevent future manual handling of the SAMBA groups and users.